# Read pinned clipboard history of my old windows installation

Tags: windows, clipboard

I reinstalled Windows today, and I wanted to access my previous installation's clipboard pinned items.

To my knowledge, said pinned items are in "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Clipboard\Pinned"

However, the files it contains seem to be crypted and I can't read them.

Is there any way for me to still access their content ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the files are encrypted, just in a binary format. The format of such file is most likely private to Windows (no published documentation), so don't even start trying to understand it.

You should be able to see your clipboard history and pinned items by pressing `Win` + `V`.

Comment: I thank you for this answer, however it was for my previous Windows installation, not the one I currently use